# Expected number of rolls to get 1 followed by 2

Tags: probability

We have a fair, six-sided dice. The questions are

> 1. What's the expected number of rolls to get 1 followed by 1?
> 2. What's the expected number of rolls to get 1 followed by 2?

Let $E$ be the expected time to get '11'. From the geometric distribution, we know that it takes on average 6 rolls to get a 1. Let us roll until we have a 1. Then there is a $1/6$ chance of being done in the next roll
$$E = 6 + \frac{1}{6} \cdot 1 + \frac{5}{6}(1 + E) \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad E = 42.$$
I am fairly certain that my solution is correct for the first one, but I am a bit confused about the logic for the second one. I know its very similar to the first one but with a twist. Let $E$ be the expected time to get '12'. Then we first have to roll on average 6 times, after which we have a $1/6$ probability of being done (2), a $4/6$ chance of starting all over (3,4,5,6), and a $1/6$ probability of making no progress (1). Then
$$E = 6 + \frac16\cdot 1 + \frac46 \cdot (1 + E) + \frac16 \cdot (1+6) \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad E=48.$$
Is the $(1+6)$ part right? For some reason I don't think it is.

Comment: Indeed the $(1+6)$ term is incorrect and should be replaced by $(1+F)$ where $F$ denotes the mean number of throws to get `12` starting from `1`. Thus, by the reasoning you used to get the equation on $E$, one gets $F=\frac16+\frac16(1+F)+\frac46(1+E)$. Solving the $(E,F)$-system yields $E=36$.

Comment: Aha this makes sense. Is there a way to solve the problem without solving a system (as in, make it all one easy equation like the '11' case)? In particular, this was an interview question where I did not have pen and paper and a time limit.

Comment: Yes: by the law of large numbers, after $n\gg1$ throws, there are approximately $n/36$ occurrences of the motive `12`. Since after one such occurrence, one starts afresh to produce another motive `12`, the mean time to produce one is $36$. The argument breaks for the motive `11` because once some `11` is realized, we already have one `1` at our disposal, possibly, to produce the next `11`. Hence, after the first `11`, the next ones are closer from each other, which explains why the time needed to produce the first motive `11` is $>36$.